# Reorder Java Array

Tags: java

I have the following command line argument:

java Knapsack 200 3 500 9 200 8 10

How can I store each argument like the following?

```
item worth weight
0     200   3
1     500   9
2     200   8
```

I have the following for loop:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < items.length; j+=2) {
            items[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[j]);
        }
        System.out.println(i + "\t" + items[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't. Create an object to store the item, worth, weight inside and loop through your inputs three at a time creating those objects and adding them to the array.

Answer (score 0):

For one, your initial loop is only increasing by one each time. I would do something like this:

```
int id = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < items.length + 1; i += 2) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s\t%s\t%s", Integer.toString(id++), items[i], items[i + 1]));
}
```